# Contest-List: Separate site or simply scroll down on homepage

Tags: website-design, navigation, user-behavior, layout, user-expectation

My webapplication concept is all about some kinds of contests in which users can participate. Each contest has a minimal amount of information that will be displayed while viewing the list. As for now, my homepage simply consists of a header and a huge slider explaining how the site works.

My question: Should I add the contest-list at the bottom of the page, so that the user has to scroll-down to see the contests (Scroll-down can also happen through javascript)? Or should I keep the list on another page that has to be accessed first?

My personal opinion on this:
For new users, I think the separate page would be better, as it keeps two aspects of the site separated. Experienced users though may want to go directly to the contest-list and could be bothered by having to go to another page.

Here an image to explain the difference:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ2aC.jpg

Comment: How important a list of contests are to your audience? Does most of your traffic go to a list of contests most of the time or do majority of people go to other sections of the site besides this list?

Comment: @Igorek I think that it is pretty important, as my goal is to get about half of the users to the contest-list site and the other half to another part of my site.

Comment: what is the other part?

Comment: @Igorek In the other part users are able to create contests (Thats why my goal is to get half of the users to this part, and half of the users to the other part: I need the contest-creators & contest-"takers" to be balanced.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I add the contest-list at the bottom of the page, so that the user has to scroll-down to see the contests or should I keep the list on another page that has to be accessed first?

**Why not do both?**

As you mentioned in your comments, most of users either go to see a list of contests and others go to the page to start a new contest. Both of these actions can be housed on the homepage to capture both groups of traffic (see example wireframe below)

[image: Homepage for contests]

#### Do I need a separate page if I already have contests on my homepage?

**Yes** - you DON'T want to put every single contest onto the homepage. Maybe the most recent, most popular or paid? and limit the list to top 7 or 10... Give yousr visitors buttons / links / CTA's to navigate to a separate page of all contests where they can browser, filter, search, etc..

Comment: Oh wow, actually that is an awesome idea, thanks for the answer! (PS: Also, how did you create such a beautiful wireframe?)

Comment: @GandalfSchmidt, I used [Balsamiq Mockups](https://balsamiq.com/). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any navigation?

you could add "Contest" as a navigation Item, and when the user click it, automatically scroll down.

I don't know your application but in my opinion, a separate page would be better for old users.
As a new user, exploring your site, i would like to see what this contest are.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it all on one page. You can have a button at the top that just anchors you to the section of the page where contests list starts but keep it all one. By now users are conditioned into scrolling ( i.e. FB, twitter, etc...) There is no reason to create a whole separate page just to display a list of contests.